# Possible ways for testing automation of ASP.NET2.0/ADO.NET project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, unit-testing, ado.net

What approaches could you please suggest me for testing (using NUnit?) a complex ASP.NET 2.0 solution - large web-site with a number of depending assemblies (App_Code is inside on of them).

I want to test web pages functionality - will web controls like GridView, FormView, DetailsView, etc insert and load the data from SQL Server 2008 properly?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Pex

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

We use Selenium Remote Control from NUnit and it works very well. We run tests as part of build process.